# BackHandler after changing app state doesn't invoke subscribed function

Tags: react-native

Steps to reproduce:

1. press home hardware button (app state is changing to background)
2. open app and try press back button

Expected result: handleBackButtonClick is invoked
     Actually result: handleBackButtonClick isn't invoked

My code:

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

componentWillMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

handleAppStateChange = (state: AppStateStatus) => {
    if (state === 'active') {
        console.log('LISTEN');
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress);
    } else {
        console.log('UNLISTEN');
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress);
    }
};

handleBackButtonClick = () => {
    console.log('press back')
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure what you are trying to accomplish but based on the react-native documentation on [BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler), you may want to place the `eventListener` on `componentDidMount` to be safe. Your handler generally would then decide how to *back* E.g.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    this.goBack(); // works best when the goBack is async
    return true;
  }
```

Also, unless defined somewhere else `this.onBackPress` would be `undefined` in your context.